# What's the name of this 3D overprinted text effect

Tags: text, 3d, effects

**What is this kind of 3D text effect called?** It's made with either overprinted letters, or different colored layers into a fake 3D effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The 'effect' is simply called a 'bevel'.

You can emulate it to an extent using any number of bevel filters in a variety of illustration and design software products, but in this particular example, it was drawn this way. Either in a program such as Adobe Illustrator, or by using an existing typeface already drawn this way. An example of such a face is [Detroit](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/matchandkerosene/detroit/&refby=x).

As a typeface, the effect is achieved by layering different variants of the same typeface--each variant a separate color you can create.